# Searching for a string in a single column in a table within an ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, asp.net-mvc-3, search

I have a table named Orders that has a column named OrderCode that stores a string that I randomly generate at the time of creation.

I want to make sure this string (OrderCode) is unique before I save it to my table.

How I have attempted to do this:

```
        bool isUnique = false;
        var order = new Order();
        var code = RandomCode.Generate();
        while (isUnique == false) // checks to see if the code we generated is unique among all generated codes, if not, will generate another code
        {
            var activeOrders = storeDB.Orders.Find("OrderCode", code);
            if (activeOrders == null)
            {
                isUnique = true;
            }
            else
            {
                code = RandomCode.Generate();
            }
        }

        order.OrderCode = code;
```

The problem appears to be that the `DbSet<TEntity>.Find` Method is actually used to search through primary keys - but I am needing to search for a string that is not a primary key.

What is a correct approach to this situation?

Comment: Why not use a Guid for the OrderCode, which pretty much insures that it is unique?

Comment: Can I create a 7 character long code using Guid?

Comment: You can get Guid down to 22 chars using base64 encoding.  Seven chars is pretty hard to ensure a unique code.  If this is small because of wanting something that humans can handle I would recommend going to 10 chars.  People can remember a telephone number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (context.Orders.Any(o => o.OrderCode == code))
{
  // key found
}

if (context.Orders.FirstOrDefault(o => o.OrderCode == code) != null)
{
  // key found
}
```

May I ask why you don't just use a `System.Guid` though ([`Guid.NewGuid()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid.aspx).`ToString()`)? This would virtually eliminate this kind of issue.

Comment: I agree ... GUID is the best solution for this unique string problem

Comment: My understanding was that I would be unable to create just a 7 character string using that?

Comment: @miscusermandude: So why do you have a VARCHAR(7) as your key? Are you under constraints of your own or someone else's? I would look in to using int/unique column instead.

Comment: I am needing an easily readable 7 character string that people can communicate quickly verbally (no o vs 0 or l vs I confusion).  Think of a coupon code that you want to quickly be able to give someone over the phone.

Comment: @miscusermandude: Are you expecting more than 10 million orders? most sites I deal with have numeric order numbers which work very well (then CustSvc verifies name/address to prevent error). I just see it as very heavy to re-check a database every time to make an entry.

Comment: No I am not.  Each time a user makes a purchase they are given a code that can be used one time for something.  Once they use this code their code becomes inactive.  Ideally - I will generate this random code, they will use it, and I will set a bool "active" to false to explain that the code has been used.  So ultimately I will only be searching through OrderCodes on rows that have the Active bool set to true.  There should only be a few thousand of these active at any given time.